# How to convert ArrayList<String> to int[] in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I read Bert Bates and Katie Sierra's book Java and have a problem.

> **The Task:** to make the game "Battleship" with 3 classes via using ArrayList.
>
> **Error:** the method setLocationCells(ArrayList < String >) in the type
>   SimpleDotCom is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

I understand that ArrayList only will hold objects and never primatives. So handing over the list of locations (which are int's) to the ArrayList won't work because they are primatives. But how can I fix it?

*Code:*

```
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numOfGuesses = 0;

        GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();

        SimpleDotCom theDotCom = new SimpleDotCom();

        int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

         int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum+1, randomNum+2};

         theDotCom.setLocationCells(locations);

        boolean isAlive = true;

        while(isAlive) {    

            String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter the number");

            String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);

            numOfGuesses++;

            if (result.equals("Kill")) {
                isAlive = false;
                System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + "  guesses");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleDotCom {

    private ArrayList<String> locationCells;

    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc) {
        locationCells = loc;
    }

    public String checkYourself(String stringGuess) {

        String result = "Miss";

        int index = locationCells.indexOf(stringGuess);

        if (index >= 0) {
            locationCells.remove(index);

            if(locationCells.isEmpty()) {
                result = "Kill";
            } else {
                result = "Hit";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class GameHelper {

    public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.print(prompt + " ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if (inputLine.length() == 0)
                return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:" + e);
        }
        return inputLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you store integers as strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> convert ArrayList to int[] in Java

## Reason for Basic Solution

Here's a simple example of converting `ArrayList<String>` to `int[]` in Java. I think it's better to give you an example not specific to your question, so you can observe the concept and learn.

## Step by Step

If we have an `ArrayList<String>` defined below

`List<String> numbersInAList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "-3");`

Then the easiest solution for a beginner would be to loop through each list item and add to a new array. This is because the elements of the list are type `String`, but you need type `int`.

We start by creating a new array of the same size as the List

`int[] numbers = new int[numbersInAList.size()];`

We then iterate through the list

`for (int ndx = 0; ndx < numbersInAList.size(); ndx++) {`

Then inside the loop we start by casting the `String` to `int`

`int num = Integer.parseInt(numbersInAList.get(ndx));`

But there's a problem. We don't always know the String will contain a numeric value. `Integer.parseInt` throws an exception for this reason, so we need to handle this case. For our example we'll just print a message and skip the value.

```
try {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(numbersInAList.get(ndx));
} catch (NumberFormatException formatException) {
   System.out.println("Oops, that's not a number");
}
```

We want this new `num` to be placed in an array, so we'll place it inside the array we defined

`numbers[ndx] = num;`

or combine the last two steps

`numbers[ndx] = Integer.parseInt(numbersInAList.get(ndx));`

## Final Result

If we combine all of the code from "Step by Step", we get the following

```
List<String> numbersInAList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "-3");
int[] numbers = new int[numbersInAList.size()];

for (int ndx = 0; ndx < numbersInAList.size(); ndx++) {
   try {
      numbers[ndx] = Integer.parseInt(numbersInAList.get(ndx));
   } catch (NumberFormatException formatException) {
      System.out.println("Oops, that's not a number");
   }
}
```

## Important Considerations

Note there are more elegant solutions, such as using Java 8 streams. Also, it's typically discouraged to store `ints` as `Strings`, but it can happen, such as reading input.

Comment: You're welcome invzbl3. Let me know if you have questions after reading. Also, please remember to indicate the most helpful response to your question with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you call `setLocationCells(ArrayList<String>)` in your code, but if the only problem is storing integers into an `ArrayList` there is a solution:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myArray.add(1);
myArray.add(2);
```

It is true that you can't use primitive types as generics, but you can use the Java wrapper types (in this case, `java.lang.Integer`).

Comment: still, use `Integer`s instead of `String`s and it will solve your problem.